# Back-reference to glossary entry links to wrong page

Tags: glossaries, back-referencing

I am using back-references from glossary entries and they mostly work fine. However, if I have a paragraph breaking on a new page, then the back-reference links to the page where the paragraph started, even if the glossary term appears on the new page.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
\glstoctrue
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{hank}{
    name={hank},
    description={A metal or plastic clip that is fixed to the luff of the jib and used to attach the jib to the forestay.}
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

The jib is usually stored in the cabin, so it must first be brought on the deck and unfolded. The jib has three corners, each having its role and they must not be mixed up. The front corner is attached to the shackle on the deck; jib halyard is attached to the top corner, while jib sheets are attached to the rear corner of the jib. Jib sheets are lines that are used to control the jib during sailing; there are two of them, one for each side of the boat. Jib sheets run through the jib car and then to the cockpit. Depending on the size of the jib and the type of rig, jib sheets are led either on the inner or the outer side of the shrouds. The jib is usually attached to the forestay by using \glspl{hank} (metal or plastic clips). Hanks are fixed to the jib and all of them should be attached to the forestay before hoisting the jib. The normal sequence of attaching the hanks is from bottom up.

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

This problem sometimes happens even if there is no paragraph break, e.g. when new paragraphs starts on new page after a figure. I would like back-references to always point to the page where the term appears.

Comment: I get the correct page 2 with `glossaries` version 4.41. What version do you have?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot with "overleaf" (verison fo `glossaries` 4.30) I can confirm that his/her issue exists... But I think this is because of a reason: "If you want to find in the text a glossary entry, you are interested in the whole text (paragraph) that it appears"

Comment: @koleygr It's a bug that's been fixed. Overleaf's TeX distribution is getting a bit dated.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot.. Thanks for the info... I thought, that this was the way of glossaries' decision about their links.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I have been using version 4.32. After updating to v4.41 this issue no longer exists. Thank you for answering promptly!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due updating the TeX distribution fixed the issue.